# Can't get alignment to work in Labeled function

Tags: output-formatting, labeling, alignment

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the Mathematica function `Labeled` to print an expression with a ***left-justified*** label on top of it. The Help page for `Labeled` says that

> Labeled[expr, lbl, pos] places lbl at a position specified by pos

and that `pos` may have the form `{side, align}`, in which case the label appears "on the specified side with the specified alignment." It then says that `side` may be either `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, or `Bottom`, while `align` may be either `Center`, `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, or `Bottom`.  Although it's possible that I've misinterpreted this, I would have thought that the following code would thus place the label "Foo" left-justified on top of the expression `{a, b, c, d}`:

```
Labeled[
    Framed[ {a, b, c, d} ],
     "Foo",
     {Top, Left}
]
```

The above code, though, places the label "Foo" ***centered*** on top of the expression `{a, b, c, d}`.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I get the same on Win 8.1 Pro in 10.4.1 and 11.0.  I think it could be a bug.  Report to WRI.

Comment: Many thanks, @Edmund!  That was my guess as well, but based on the response from @Mr.Wizard, I wonder whether there's a problem with my code and/or my analysis.  I'm looking forward to reading his response to the comments I just appended to his response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a syntax ambiguity arising from the allowance for this form:

```
Labeled[Framed[{a, b, c, d}], {"Foo", "Bar"}, {Top, Left}]
```

[image]

Instead you need:

```
Labeled[Framed[{a, b, c, d}], "Foo", {{Top, Left}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, Mr. Wizard!  First of all, many thanks for providing a way to implement this correctly.In my experience, you really are a Wizard, so I want to make sure I understand what your diagnosis and treatment.  Just to clarify, are you saying that this is, in fact, a bug in Mathematica (that is to say, that my original code *should have* worked), but that Wolfram's bug is the result of their allowing a syntax that introduces an ambiguity?

Comment: Many thanks, @Mr.Wizard!  Although your solution indeed works, I'm not sure *why*, since I don't see a syntactic form on the Help page that allows a *single* symbol (representing a single label) as the second argument, but a *list* of {side, align} position specifications as the third argument.  If I'm interpreting the Help page correctly, it seems like the expression Labeled[ Framed[{a, b, c, d}], {"Foo"}, {{Top, Left}} ] should yield the behavior I was looking for (which it does), but not the expression Labeled[ Framed[{a, b, c, d}], "Foo", {{Top, Left}} ].  Is there an error in my analysis?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, @Mr.Wizard. Regarding the syntactic ambiguity of Labeled[ Framed[{a, b, c, d}], "Foo", {Top, Left} ]: Couldn’t Mathematica interpret the 3rd arg of a 3-arg form of Labeled based on the type of the 2nd arg? If the 2nd arg is a *symbol*, {Top, Left} would be interpreted as I'd intended, but if the 2nd arg is a *list*, "Top" would apply to the first label in that list, while "Left" would apply to the second label. It may be that Mathematica *doesn’t* parse it this way, but I’m not sure I see any *inherent* ambiguity. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @gratefuluser Honestly I did not analyze it to this degree, I just hoped to offer a quick solution.  I tend to agree (without exhaustive consideration) that the function could recognize `Labeled[x, "foo", {Top, Left}]` as you intended, but I am not prepared to say that the fact that it does not is a bug.  If you do contact support regarding this I am curious to know what they say.

Comment: Got it.  I've entered my acceptance, and very much appreciate your response.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the following does not work as expected: `Labeled["aabbccdd", {"foo", "bar"}, {{Top, Left}, {Top, Right}}]`. No idea why not.

Comment: @István I don't believe I have seen any example where there is more than one label on a given side.

Comment: Me neither, but i) the argument format does allow for multiple labels on the same side without warning and ii) the documentation never states that there is such limitation. So I expected it to work (though I knew it wouldn't, but that is only because I know that it is implemented by `Grid` or similar with a limited number of positions instead of `Graphics` and practically unlimited coordinates).